# how to add a constant line to hvplot

Tags: python, pandas, holoviews, hvplot

How to add a horizontal line to a hvplot ? Holoviews has .HLine and .VLine but not sure how to access it via pandas.hvplot or hvplot

here is a sample dataframe and plotting script.

```py
import pandas as pd
import hvplot.pandas

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[100], 'B':[20]})
df = df.reset_index()

print(df)
#   index   A       B
#0  0       100     20

# create plot
plot = df.hvplot.bar(y=['A', 'B'], x='index', 
              rot=0, subplots=False, stacked=True)

plot
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would just **overlay** a holoviews [hv.HLine()](http://holoviews.org/reference/elements/matplotlib/HLine.html) to your plot like so:

```
import holoviews as hv

your_hvplot * hv.HLine(60)
```

Using **the * symbol** in the code is an easy of putting the HLine on top of your other plot. 
 This is called an [Overlay](http://holoviews.org/reference/containers/bokeh/Overlay.html).

---

If you also need **a label with your HLine**, this SO question contains an example for that:
 [How do I get a full-height vertical line with a legend label in holoviews + bokeh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55050557/how-do-i-get-a-full-height-vertical-line-with-a-legend-label-in-holoviews-boke)

---

Your **sample code** with the horizontal line would look like this then:

```
# import libraries
import pandas as pd
import hvplot.pandas
import holoviews as hv

# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[100], 'B':[20]})

# create plot
plot = df.hvplot.bar(
    y=['A', 'B'], 
    stacked=True, 
    xaxis='', 
    title='Adding horizontal line hv.HLine() to plot with * overlay',
)

# create separate hline 
# for demonstration purposes I added some styling options
hline = hv.HLine(60)
hline.opts(
    color='red', 
    line_dash='dashed', 
    line_width=2.0,
)

# add hline to plot using * which overlays the hline on the plot
plot * hline
```

---

**Final result:** 
[image: adding hv.hline to hvplot]

Comment: thanks for showing how to avoid using 'index', that was ugly hack.

Comment: yeah in this case, if you don't specify the 'x' argument, hvplot() will automatically take the index of your dataframe as the 'x' argument. But sometimes i also find myself using .reset_index() in cases where it doesn't work :)